# Issue with dplyr and cut for time intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, cut, cumsum, difftime

I am trying to split by data into 5 sec time intervals and group them using dplyr.
Below is my original data - I have date and time in separate columns which I have later combined using Posixct

`structure(list(Date = c("10/30/2013", "10/30/2013", "10/30/2013", 
"10/30/2013", "10/30/2013", "10/30/2013", "10/30/2013", "10/30/2013", 
"10/30/2013", "10/30/2013", "10/30/2013", "10/30/2013", "10/30/2013", 
"10/30/2013", "10/30/2013"), Time = c("20:06:57", "20:07:13", 
"20:07:25", "20:07:30", "20:08:16", "20:08:17", "20:08:26", "20:09:05", 
"20:09:06", "20:09:07", "20:09:37", "20:09:38", "20:09:55", "20:12:34", 
"20:14:15"), ID = c("M1", "M1", "M1", "M3", "M1", "M1", "M8", 
"M9", "M9", "M9", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M5", "M1")), .Names = c("Date", 
"Time", "ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))`

Attaching my code below

```
data$datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(data$Date, data$Time), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") 
data_order <- data %>%  arrange(datetime,ID)      
data_order$group <-  data_order  %>% group_by(by5sec=cut(datetime, breaks= "5 secs",right =T),ID) %>% group_indices()
```

While some observations are grouped right , some are wrong. I have tried 2 versions - removing the "right=T" and keeping it and I got different groups , but had errors in both versions. I have also tried using as.numeric,as.posixct et all before the cut in vain

Attaching the output for both versions.Red ones are wrongly coded as 2 different groups.

****Version 1 **"right = T"**  for cut****

[image]

****Version 2 **"right = F"**  for cut****

[image]

Could someone please help in solving this,I have spent quite some time and its been a goose chase given my knowledge of R . All I want is 5 sec breaks for the same ID(group should change for a new ID).

**Desired output**

[image]

Comment: added "expected output" for more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on the output images you show. Based on your problem description, how about something like this?

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    unite(datetime, 1:2, sep = " ", remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(
        datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
        datetime.by5sec = as.numeric(cut(datetime, "sec")) %/% 5 + 1);
#        datetime       Date     Time ID datetime.by5sec
#1  2013-10-30 20:06:57 10/30/2013 20:06:57 M1               1
#2  2013-10-30 20:07:13 10/30/2013 20:07:13 M1               4
#3  2013-10-30 20:07:25 10/30/2013 20:07:25 M1               6
#4  2013-10-30 20:07:30 10/30/2013 20:07:30 M3               7
#5  2013-10-30 20:08:16 10/30/2013 20:08:16 M1              17
#6  2013-10-30 20:08:17 10/30/2013 20:08:17 M1              17
#7  2013-10-30 20:08:26 10/30/2013 20:08:26 M8              19
#8  2013-10-30 20:09:05 10/30/2013 20:09:05 M9              26
#9  2013-10-30 20:09:06 10/30/2013 20:09:06 M9              27
#10 2013-10-30 20:09:07 10/30/2013 20:09:07 M9              27
#11 2013-10-30 20:09:37 10/30/2013 20:09:37 M1              33
#12 2013-10-30 20:09:38 10/30/2013 20:09:38 M1              33
#13 2013-10-30 20:09:55 10/30/2013 20:09:55 M1              36
#14 2013-10-30 20:12:34 10/30/2013 20:12:34 M5              68
#15 2013-10-30 20:14:15 10/30/2013 20:14:15 M1              88
```

Explanation: `datetime.by5sec` gives the 5 sec bin index into which `datetime` falls. So the first entry sits in bin 1. The second entry is within the 4th 5 sec bin, i.e. within 20 seconds from the first entry, and so on. Here I made use of integer division `%/% 5`, since [`cut.POSIXct`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.POSIXt.html) only allows you to bin by second as interval.

---

### Update

The following reproduces your expected output:

```
df %>%
    unite(datetime, 1:2, sep = " ", remove = FALSE) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(
        datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
        difftime = difftime(datetime, lag(datetime, default = 0))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(
        group = cumsum(abs(difftime) >= 5)) %>%
    select(Date, Time, ID, datetime, group);
## A tibble: 15 x 5
#   Date       Time     ID    datetime            group
#   <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <dttm>              <int>
# 1 10/30/2013 20:06:57 M1    2013-10-30 20:06:57     1
# 2 10/30/2013 20:07:13 M1    2013-10-30 20:07:13     2
# 3 10/30/2013 20:07:25 M1    2013-10-30 20:07:25     3
# 4 10/30/2013 20:07:30 M3    2013-10-30 20:07:30     4
# 5 10/30/2013 20:08:16 M1    2013-10-30 20:08:16     5
# 6 10/30/2013 20:08:17 M1    2013-10-30 20:08:17     5
# 7 10/30/2013 20:08:26 M8    2013-10-30 20:08:26     6
# 8 10/30/2013 20:09:05 M9    2013-10-30 20:09:05     7
# 9 10/30/2013 20:09:06 M9    2013-10-30 20:09:06     7
#10 10/30/2013 20:09:07 M9    2013-10-30 20:09:07     7
#11 10/30/2013 20:09:37 M1    2013-10-30 20:09:37     8
#12 10/30/2013 20:09:38 M1    2013-10-30 20:09:38     8
#13 10/30/2013 20:09:55 M1    2013-10-30 20:09:55     9
#14 10/30/2013 20:12:34 M5    2013-10-30 20:12:34    10
#15 10/30/2013 20:14:15 M1    2013-10-30 20:14:15    11
```

Explanation: Calculate the time difference between two successive `datetime` entries, grouped by `ID`; `group` is then the cumulative sum of all time differences `>=5`.

Comment: Thanks Evers. The problem I want to solve here is, given a datetime , I want to look at entries that are within 5 secs and group them,provided their ID's match. Both our codes take the first entry as reference and bins them. But I want a moving 5-sec window. I want #8,#9,#10 as a single group instead of 2 as the time lag between them is less than 5 sec.

Comment: @Vinds. But #8, #9, #10 fall into *different* 5 sec bins. That's just a result of your first entry being the reference. I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Vinds I've updated my solution to include a method that reproduces your expected output. Please take a look.

Comment: @evers..thank u .. the code works almost right, except that i want #5 and #6 in a group. #4 and #5 should not be grouped since the ID's are different and also the time difference is more than 5 secs. A little modification to calculate time diff only when the ID's are same would do the trick ? ur thoughts??

Comment: @Vinds OK, I understand; please take a look at my updated solution. This should do the job.

Comment: @Vinds. Try again, there was a typo in my code (I've edited my update). BTW, an upvote would have been appreciated by now.

Comment: @evers this works for the given data. However, when I changed #11 to  20:09:08 to check if its honoring the change of ID the code didnt work and I got  #8,#9,#10,#11 as one group. I then tried including an `iflese` for the ID check but am not able to get the `else` bit right. "          `mutate(group = ifelse(ID == lag(ID), cumsum(abs(
    difftime(datetime, lag(datetime, default = 0))
  ) >= 5),group))`   Just one step away from the required solution. Is there an option to only use `if` here ? ur thoughts ?

Comment: @Vind It *does* honour the `ID` if I change #11. Have a look at my revised update. The issue was that I re-calculated `difftime` in `group`, which then ignored the `ID` grouping. The key is to `difftime` while entries are *grouped*, but then calculate the `cumsum` on the *ungrouped* entries.

Comment: Wow..@evers, Thank you very much, I was stuck on this for nearly a week. This works perfectly now. I have tried to upvote many times , but I think I dont have enough points for my vote to be visible. I am just learning to use SO.  +100 for your solution and patience to help me in solving this :))

Comment: @Vinds Glad it worked out! You will be able to upvote if you have >15 rep, by clicking the little arrow symbol next to my solution. Also please close the question by setting the check mark next to the solution.

Comment: @evers I have an issue.The solution given,groups everything when the cumsum is >=5.Am back to my initial problem i.e to not look at immediate time lags. Given a datetime   I  want to include only the next n datetimes that are within a '5sec' window,provided the ID's are same.  For eg. if I have `16:00:04
16:00:05
16:00:07
16:00:08
16:00:12
16:00:13` where `ID=M9` the solution provided will group all observations as one group. It does not cut at `16:00:12` and create a new group . I have tried a couple of conditions on cumsum but doesnt seem to work. Could you please have a look ? thanks

Comment: @Vinds Yes, that will not work. This goes back to the binning vs. time difference issue. If it's binning you're interested in, look at my first solution with `datetime.by5sec`; that's an entirely different situation from the situation you've been describing in the last 2 days. *Binning* is not the same as *grouping*. TBH I am unsure what it is you're after.

Comment: @Evers. Apologies for not being precise.All I want is to do grouping on 2 levels. 1)Change in ID shld give me a new group . 2) within this  ID group , I want  a further 5 sec group based on time. Given a time i want look at next n entries that r within 5 secs and group them. I want moving references , so binning did not work earlier.. So within single ID i can have more than one group based on time interval. You could think of this as inter groups on ID's and Intra groups based on times. Am i making any sense now ?

Comment: @Vinds Nope, I don't think this will work (or makes sense). If you want to bin based on the first time in an `ID` group, you might always end up with two entries that are only `1sec` apart but that end up in different bins. And you want binning because you want to break up entries such as the `ID=M9` example you described previously. I'm sure it will be possible to come up with a different (kludgy) solution for a different sample dataset; but I don't think there is a general & robust solution that will hold up against all cases, so I will stop here.

Comment: @evers.. I understand this is a one-off case .. thank you for your inputs and patience in trying to understand the issue and clarifying about binning and time differences. TBH I was not aware of how binning worked before this.